How to compare two tsx elements in react + tsx
i want to compare two react tsx elements. i am still new to react and tsx. but i am unale to do so even after copying and pasting the exact elements to compare. Can you tell me why and how to fix it?
Here is where i want to compare
function placeTile(index: number) {
    if (
      tiles[index] ===                  //Compare here
      (
        <div className="filler" id=".">
          .
        </div>
      )
    ) {
      let updateTile = tiles.slice();
      updateTile[index] = (
        <div className="filled" id={move}>
          {move}
        </div>
      );
      console.log("Filled a spot");
      setTiles(updateTile);
    } else {
      console.log("This is filled spot " + index);
    }
  }

The 'tiles' is an array of the very same tsx elements declared as follows
let createTileSetup = Array(9).fill(
    <div className="filler" id=".">
      .
    </div>
  );

const [tiles, setTiles] = useState(createTileSetup);

Using something like tiles[index].id to get the id isnt working. It is just saying it is undefined
If there is another way please tell me. their ids are different but i dont know how to compare those either. any help is appreciated

The reason your strategy doesn't work is because for Javascript objects, the === operator tests for identity (ie: whether they refer to the same object) rather than any sort of equivalence structurally.
To fix this, use some other test to check for equality of the objects. To test, for example, the className of your <div>s, you could write

if (
      // .props.className gets the className of an HTML tag
      tiles[index].props.className === 'filler'
    )
{
    // Do something
}

Be wary that if you do this, you must also check that each tiles[index] is indeed an HTML tag. Otherwise, tiles[index].props.className may cause an error accessing property className of undefined.
Hope this helps.

wait, why do we have to add .props in between?

this has worked magically, but what was the issue with tiles[index].id like stuff. i have seen that work in js tutorials and stuff. I am new so any help towards where to study this is appreciated

It's all about the properties of the object you're accessing. If I have a variable const element = <div className="test"></div>, then I need to access the className attribute. It turns out, element.className won't work, because className is not a valid attribute.
I can use console.log(JSON.stringify(element)). This will expose element as an actual JSON string, and I can see which attributes exist on the object. When I do this, I see {"type":"div","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"className":"test"},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}. So element.props.className returns "test".

The choice about which attributes exist on the object is a decision made by TSX in encoding your HTML element. Everything in Javascript is an object. If you need to figure out how to interact with the object, you should console.log it.

thanks. this would genuinely help me alot in the next project

compare properties of the elements rather than the elements themselves.  instead of directly comparing JSX elements, compare the id property of the tiles. If the id matches the expected value (in this case "."), update the tile at the specified index.
const initialTiles = Array(9).fill({ className: "filler", id: ".", content: "." });
const [tiles, setTiles] = useState(initialTiles);
function placeTile(index: number) {
  if (tiles[index].id === ".") {  // Compare the id property
    let updateTile = [...tiles];
    updateTile[index] = { className: "filled", id: move, content: move }; 
    setTiles(updateTile);
  } else {
    console.log("This is a filled spot " + index);
  }
}
return (
  <div className="tile-container">
    {tiles.map((tile, index) => (
      <div
        key={index}
        className={tile.className}
        id={tile.id}
        onClick={() => placeTile(index)}
      >
        {tile.content}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);


so you are proposing using object instead of html tags. This is doable option but that way i have to change a lot in my codebase. Still, thanks for the answer. the above answer from garlic_bread_eater has worked, idk why but will find out. any comment from your side is also appreciated

I feel using objects to manage state instead of directly using JSX elements is a recommended approach because comparing simple properties like id or className is much easier and more reliable than comparing complex JSX elements directly and also  managing state with plain objects helps keep your component's state predictable and easy to debug. My thought though

i agree to that. i just learnt react and the base code was from the react documentation i learnt and wrote. then i tried to modify it to use id and classes to make it usable in css, which was not possible before. there i stuck to the problem. had i seen this coming, i would've gone with objects in the first place
